# Get monthly profit in webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need some help getting the monthly profit as this image below:
[image]

My database table is named `orders` and has the following fields `id`, `totalprice`, `date`, `status`.

My `date` is saved as `datetime` eg: `2016-11-08 20:10:12`
The calculation must be made monthly as the picture and only for orders with `status` equal to `DELIVERED`.

At the moment my code is only showing the last month and it's not even close to what I want to see, here is my code at the moment...

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Status</th> <th>Total Price</th> <th>Time</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
        $cons_no="DELIVERED";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(totalprice) AS value_sum FROM orders WHERE status = '$cons_no' AND date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $sum = $row['value_sum'];
        //$query2 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = '$cons_no' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = '$cons_no' AND date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()";
        $results2 = $conn->query($query2);
        if($results2){
            $currentDate = false;
            while($row2 = $results2->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row2['status']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2['totalprice']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row2['date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
          }

        }
    ?>

        <td><?php echo "$".number_format($sum); ?></td>
    </tbody>
```

It would be great if someone can help me reach the image result, I have tried some stuff that I found here in StackOverflow but nothing helped me reaching to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This query would give you the sum of all orders for a year,month. Use it in your code to convert it into text.

```
SELECT SUM(totalprice),* FROM [orders] GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate),MONTH(OrderDate);
```

Comment: **protip** add `WITH ROLLUP` to the end of your `GROUP BY` clause to return an extra row at the end containing the total for all rows returned